# Json object doesn't echo on php page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I think I am getting close on this, but for some reason the json data doesn't print out when it gets to the php page.

Here is my form with some dummy data:

```
<form id="add_form" action="javascript:void(0);">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" value="5" name="dogs" id="dogs" />
        <input type="text" value="10" name="cats" id="cats" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Here is the related function (runs from a button, not shown above):

```
function add()
{
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    url: 'add.php',
    data: { json: $('#add_form').serialize() },
    success: success
    });
}
```

Finally the php that I can't seem to make work:

```
$json_object = json_decode($_POST['json']);
echo $json_object;
```

What I am really after is being able to get at the values for each element in the form (no matter how many form elements there are). As always, appreciate any advice you are willing to give.

Comment: print_r($json_object) and print_r($_POST['json']) just to check if the data is getting posted back

Comment: you are passing data as post so it will be access using $_POST. try my answer it will be work.

Comment: *"for some reason the json data doesn't print out"* You are not sending JSON at all.

Comment: @Deepanshu OP is decoding json but no need to use json_decode() because he is not passing the data as json. so in your comment second option you have specified it is correct just use $_POST['json'] to access, take a look at my answer.

Comment: @FelixKling you are absolutely right. same thing i have mentioned in my answer just look at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of,

```
function add()
{
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    url: 'add.php',
    data: { json: $('#add_form').serialize() },
    success: success
    });
}
```

You have to use,

```
function add()
{
    var data = $('#add_form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    url: 'add.php',
    data: data,
    success: success
    });
}
```

Then access like,

```
$_POST['dogs'];
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to decode json because your form data passed to php page as **"POST"** type. so just do as follow.

```
$json = $_POST['json'];
print_r($json);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send JSON, you have to create JSON first. `.serialize` does not return JSON, it returns a query string, as you can read in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

> The `.serialize()` method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation. It can act on a jQuery object that has selected individual form controls, such as `<input>`, `<textarea>`, and `<select>`.

Maybe you want:

```
data: { json: JSON.stringify($('#add_form').serializeArray()) },
```

but that seems to be overly complicated. Just use

```
data: $('#add_form').serialize(),
```

and access the data on the PHP side via `$_POST['form_field_1']`, etc.